# how to get an array result to screen instead of [object, object]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

When I write 'document.write() on an array result it gives me [object,Object] instead of array content.

document.write(result) was expecting the array content not [object,Object]
I am 77yrs old and learning JS, I know this Question may look naive but I have got stuck on this, trying to get the result on screen not console.log

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting [object,Object] is because you are trying to render the entire object - instead of its properties. So - assuming you are trying to print out the results of an array - as indicated in the post ... a simple array of two people with first and last names in object notation. Also - note the use of the template literals - makes it very easy to interact with and render the js content.

Simply iterate over the array and print out the indicated properties....

Note that I would not suggest to use document.write() - nor the html 'br' element - but to keep it in line with what you have presented - I did...

I would create a single string and insert it into the DOM  in a ul  / li strucuture...

```js
const results = [
  {firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith'},
  {firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe'}
]

results.forEach(result => document.write(`${result.firstName} ${result.lastName} <br/>`));
// gives 
//Bob Smith
//Jane Doe
```